# Ionic/Angular not connecting properly to nodeJS (routes work perfectly in postman

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am able to run the GET & POST requests using POSTMAN, and it works.  I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong in my app.  My GET request to the same address works just fine.

Ex., In my service:

```
createOne(route, document) {
  console.log(`create new ${route}`, document);
  console.log(`http://localhost:8080/api/${route}`);
  return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/api/${route}`, document);
}
```

This logs in the console as:
[image: Javascript Console Log]

Unfortunately, it doesn't log a thing on the nodeJS server, so I'm sure I made a mistake somewhere in the server.js file - but can't figure out where!

POST request via postman to `http://localhost:8080/api/appts` with this for raw JSON body:

```
{
    "title": "test from postman",
    "description": "test description",
    "startTime": "2020-08-04T17:40:45.521-04:00",
    "endTime": "2020-08-04T20:10-04:00",
    "allDay": false
}
```

[image: NodeJS Logs - request were done successfully from postman]

My server.js file:

```
//1. require express and call it as a function
require('./api/data/db.js');
const cron = require('node-cron');
var express = require('express');
console.log(process.env.PORT);
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./api/routes');
var json2xls = require('json2xls');

//PORT SETUP
if (process.env.PORT) {
  app.use(cors());
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
} else {
  app.set('port', 8080);
}
// MIDDLEWARE
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.method, req.url);
  next();
});
app.use(json2xls.middleware);

// ROUTING
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app/www'))); //setup primary route request folder
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //only get strings and arrays from form when false
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // tell backend to understand json data
app.use('/api', routes);
// LOAD THE SINGLE PAGE FOR IONIC
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('/app/www/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

// START SERVER LISTENING
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  var port = server.address().port; // return the port for the server listening
  console.log('RayWood API running on port ' + port); //confirm app running
});
```

My File Tree is setup as follows:
[image: File Tree]
[image: app folder file tree to show where the www folder is on build]

Seeing how the nodeJS server doesn't log the URL or REQUEST, I think the problem is in my server.js file - but I still don't know what I did wrong.  Please help!

Comment: Argh!  After I make a post, I tend to figure out the problem.  It was connecting, but I called the function and it was treating it like an Observable.  Once I subscribed, it worked!  Also had to take the use.cors() part out of the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not subscribing to Observable .If you are not familiar with Observable You can convert it to Promise please use below sample implemenation

```
createOne(route, document) {
      console.log(`create new ${route}`, document);
      console.log(`http://localhost:8080/api/${route}`);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      
    
    this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/api/${route}`,document).subscribe((resp)=>{
        console.log(resp);//This is the response from Node API
        resolve(resp);
    },(err)=>{
         reject(err)
    });
    
    });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was trying to subscribe to it from the component, rather than in the service.  I keep trying to grasp Observables, but just can't quite get it.